# BUILED FAILED CompileAssetCatalog Assets.xcassets

Tags: ios, titanium, appcelerator

**LOG**

```
BUILED FAILED

CompileAssetCatalog build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/appname.app Assets.xcassets
```

Already tried 2 latest version of sdk 5.5.1GA and 6.0.0A
Xcode 7.1

It seems okay on simulator but on device I got this error some knows about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have the right version of xcode.

For 5.5.1.GA you need at least xcode 7.3. For 6.0.0.GA you need at least xcode 8.0.

You can always check this at the [Compatibility Matrix](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Titanium_Compatibility_Matrix-section-29004837_TitaniumCompatibilityMatrix-Xcode)

Comment: Okay I will try to update mine. But I wonder why it run at the first time. I have already the app installed on my iphone 5 device,
and also its still okay on my simulator.
thanks... for the reply.

Comment: They don't say it doesn't work at all... it just might break unexpectedly. I have no clue why it did work earlier for you but it shouldn't have. You were lucky I guess ;)